# I can't extend the String prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

Here is the code

```
<script>

String.prototype.testthing = function() {
    return "working";
}

alert(String.testthing());

</script>
```

When I open this page I get the error below

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function String() { [native code] } has no method 'testthing'
```

I cannot figure out why. I've extended the Array prototype with no issues.

Comment: Well, `String !== String.prototype`.

Comment: More to the point (IMO), `Object.getPrototypeOf(String) !== String.prototype`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The code you've shown correctly extends the `String` prototype.  However you're trying to call a method on a function with `String.testthing` and not on a `string` instance.

```
alert("".testthing());  // "displays 'working'
```

If you actually want to call methods off of the `String` construct then you need to extend the prototype on `Function`

```
Function.prototype.testthing = function () { 
  return "working";
}
alert(String.testthing());
```

Comment: Why do you assign to `Function.prototype` and not `String.testthing = ...` ?

Comment: @clockworkgeek both would work (but produce diff results). I was unsure of the OP's intent but wanted to demonstrate one way of doing it .

Comment: @JaredPar is it consider bad practice to do such a thing as String.prototype.customMethod? If so, why?